# How to manage Linux server storage across sda1 and sda2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I've recently upgraded my EC2 server from a m1.small to a m1.medium (old EC2 instances I know) so I have more storage as I recently maxed it out.

When I look at the space available through Terminal I have extra space available on a /dev/sda2 directory

Is there a something I have done wrong when upgrading the server or will the storage automatically balance between the two if I reach 100% on /dev/sda1?

When I run a check I get the following information back:

[image: Terminal Output]

I've got 1% of 374Gb on /dev/sda2 available but I'm unsure how servers access this memory if /dev/sda1 reaches 100%

I'm a novice at server management so apologies if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `/dev/sda2` on an `m1` family instance is almost certainly an ephemeral disk, which you don't want to use at all until you understand how it works and what it's suitable for.  Do not move anything there that you want to keep.

Comment: You must be CAREFUL when using instance storage such as m1.  Such disk allocation are FIX and you cannot expand them.  And there is danger losing data if you store stuff inside this ephemeral  storage as @Michael-sqlbot mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing disk space and memory.

On AWS, different instance types have different memory, cpu and network performances, but the storage space is unrelated: you can extend disk space on a EC2 machine without changing its instance type, by attaching a new disk. I don't understand if your question is about disk space or memory, and I don't understand how a new disk appeared on your instance by simply upgrading it - probably it was there from instance creation.

Anyway, there isn't an "automatic balancing" of storage space - you have to manage your own files and move some files/folders to the new disk before the old one gets filled. Working on Linux, you can leverage [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) to move large directories across disk without too much hassle.

Comment: Thanks dipanda - I was meaning disk space. So I can simply attach a new disk and this will increase the storage space?If I do this then I can attempt using sym links. I'll give this a go and see what i manage to break :) Thanks for the advice

Comment: Take a look at ["Attaching an Amazon EBS Volume to an Instance"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html) and ["Making an Amazon EBS Volume Available for Use"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) official documentation pages

Answer (score 0):

1. you are using m1.medium, which given as SSD. So you just treat it as "virtual physical storage" given to you. So /dev/sda2 space  is NOT extendable to /dev/sda1
2. The SSD storage given is call "instance store". Anything inside /dev/sda are not permanent. You can REBOOT the instance and nothing lost . 
   HOWEVER, if you STOP or SHUTDOWN the instance, everything is gone. Do not pour important data in there.

   3. EBS volume normally are shown as /dev/xd* , which is extendable.

Please check out. [EC2 instance store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html)